# How to dynamicly include all source files in a folder with clojure?

Tags: clojure

I define a map of functions:

```
(ns fs
  (:require [folder/a :as a]
            [folder/b :as b]
            [folder/c :as c]) 

(def functions {:a  a/f :b b/f :c c/f})

(doseq [[_ f] functions] (f))
```

Now I want to add more namespaces within the folder, and I don't want to modify the above code. How can `functions` be dynamically populated with the `f` from each namespace in a folder.

Comment: This question is poorly phrased and confusing. If you want an answer, you should clarify:  (1) what you want, (2) what you have tried, (3) what the results were.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me, however I feel you could check https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin#import-vars and https://github.com/marick/suchwow/blob/master/test/such/f_immigration.clj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some helpers:

```
(defn directory
  "Get directory from path"
  [path]
  (clojure.java.io/file path))

(defn file-names
  "Get file names of the files in the directory."
  [files]
  (map (fn [file] (.getName file)) files))

(defn namespace
  "Remove the extension from the file name and prefix with folder-name"
  [folder-name file-name]
  (->> (clojure.string/split file-name #"\.")
       (butlast)
       (apply str)
       (str folder-name ".")
       (symbol)))
```

Then retrieve all namespaces from your folder, you need the path and the folder name:

```
(def namespaces
  (let [names (->> "/path/to/your/folder-name"
                   directory
                   file-seq ;; Gets the tree structure of the directory
                   rest ;; Get rid of the the directory name
                   file-names)]
    (map (partial namespace "folder-name") names)))
```

Next get the public functions in every namespace via [`ns-publics`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ns-publics):

```
(def functions
  (->> namespaces
       (map (juxt keyword (comp vals ns-publics)))
       (into {})))

;; => prints {:namespace-key '(fn-a fn-b) :namespace-key2 '(fn-b fn-c)}
```

Note that this gets a list of all the public functions in a namesapce after the namespace keys.

We can execute the functions as follows:

```
(doseq [[_ ns-fns] functions
        f ns-fns] (f))
```

Of course, this only works for functions that have an arity of zero. Otherwise you have to pass arguments to `f`.